# Could a new tag for Calibre editor be useful?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Right now, we have a tag for [calibre](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calibre), that covers all question about... well, Calibre.

Considering that it was born as an ebook manager, and lately incorporated a full fledged ebook editor, do you think that it could be useful to have a separate [calibre-editor](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calibre-editor) to label all those questions that are specifically related to this module of the software, an not to the more generic ebook managing part?

Having two tags could help a better categorization of questions, on the other hand it can be argued that this is unnecessary and it will just introduce ambiguity without any tangible benefit.

I don't have any strong opinion about this, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

excellent idea. Actually it reminds me, I need to check out calibre-editor (I haven't yet).